# update table data based on combo box selected value angular 2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

```
<foo-combo-box (change)="changeSelectedUser($event.target.value)" ></foo-combo-box>

<foo-table [colHeads]="getColHeads()"
              [data]="[]">
</foo-table>
```

I am new to angular 2. I was able to get the selected value, based on this value I want to updated the table data. How do i bind it with service? I have `changeselecteduser` method in my component.
I have tried to call backend service using the selected user value, but it didn't work any suggestions please

Comment: Please be more specific: you want to display the value you get from the combo or you want to display data you get from back-end?

Comment: Thanks BogdanC, based on the selected value i want to update the content of the table to get the updated data from a service.

Comment: Since you said you are able to get the selected value, with that value you can fetch the data from back-end, them you construct the table with that data. For an example on how to build the table, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40656227)